# Modify xml with namespaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xsd

I'm trying to modify predefined xml (xsd to be more specific) in TSQL.
I want to insert enumeration restriction to one of the xsd elements.

The task is to fill xsd restrictions based on a query
example:

```
create table #list(value nvarchar(100))
insert into #list values('item 1')
insert into #list values('item 2')
insert into #list values('item 3')
insert into #list values('item 4')
insert into #list values('item 5')
insert into #list values('item 6')

declare @enumeration as xml
;with xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as xs)
select @enumeration = (
    select value as '@value'
    from #list for xml path('xs:enumeration')
)

declare @schema xml
set @schema =
'<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="test">
    <xs:element name="test" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Example" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="Example">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="myList" minOccurs="1" nillable="false">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:maxLength value="50" />
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>'

set @schema.modify
    ('insert sql:variable("@enumeration")
    into (//xs:element[@name=''myList'']/xs:simpleType/xs:restriction)[1]')

select @schema
```

The problem is that code outputs unnecessary xmlns attribute

```
<xs:enumeration xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" value="item 1" />
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Good luck.  Remember:  it's often faster to train yourself to live with unnecessary but harmless namespace declarations than to make a system stop emitting them.

Comment: Not exactly your case, but you can find the answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/2f7bdfbf-8e40-456b-84e8-195318649703). In other words: if you can't ignore it and xml->nvarchar(max)->replace->xml is not elegant enough, you can always write a CLR ;)

Comment: I agree with Ozren Tkalčec Krznarić about the CLR

Comment: @tr3 the real question is can you pronounce his name

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов perfectly? not but probably I can :) I spent most of my life near slavic populations, maybe i can pronunce his name correctly :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove redundant namespace in nested query when using FOR XML PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242070/how-do-i-remove-redundant-namespace-in-nested-query-when-using-for-xml-path)

Comment: It's been 10 years with no action but perhaps a few more votes will eventually give us an actual fix rather than the workarounds people keep trying to find:  http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265956/suppress-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-for-xml-statements

Answer (score 2):

It got a bit more ugly than I hoped. Mainly because I can't use `sql:variable("@enumeration")/delete-me/node()` inside a `.modify()`.

I assume, that you can modify the generation of the `@enumeration`, as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #list (value nvarchar(100));
INSERT  INTO #list
VALUES  ('item 1');
INSERT  INTO #list
VALUES  ('item 2');
INSERT  INTO #list
VALUES  ('item 3');
INSERT  INTO #list
VALUES  ('item 4');
INSERT  INTO #list
VALUES  ('item 5');
INSERT  INTO #list
VALUES  ('item 6');

DECLARE @enumeration AS xml;
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xs)
SELECT @enumeration = (
    SELECT value AS '@value'
    FROM #list FOR XML PATH('xs:enumeration'), ROOT('delete-me'), TYPE
);
```

The idea is to use `FOR XML` with `ROOT`, so that the generated namespace is at the unnecessary root element (which can be skipped). Otherwise we would have to recreate the `xs:enumeration`-elements later.

## Two solutions

### Use `.modify()` three times

The idea:

1. We insert everything from `@enumeration` (with the unnecessary root) somewhere into the other xml
2. We copy the desired content to the right place
3. We delete the no longer needed copy of `@enumeration` in `@schema`.

```sql
DECLARE @schema xml;
SET @schema = '<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="test">
    <xs:element name="test" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Example" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="Example">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="myList" minOccurs="1" nillable="false">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:maxLength value="50" />
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>';

SET @schema.modify('insert sql:variable("@enumeration")
    into /');

SET @schema.modify('declare namespace xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
insert /delete-me/node()
    into (//xs:element[@name=''myList'']/xs:simpleType/xs:restriction)[1]');

SET @schema.modify('delete /delete-me');

SELECT  @schema;

DROP TABLE #list;
```

### `.query()` to create `@schema`

If you can change the part where `@schema` is created, you can generate `@schema` directly as `.query()` from `@enumeration`:

```sql
DECLARE @enumeration AS xml;
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xs)
SELECT @enumeration = (
    SELECT value AS '@value'
    FROM #list FOR XML PATH('xs:enumeration'), ROOT('delete-me'), TYPE
);

DECLARE @schema xml;
SET @schema = @enumeration.query('<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="test">
    <xs:element name="test" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Example" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="Example">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="myList" minOccurs="1" nillable="false">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:maxLength value="50" />
                                        {/delete-me/node()}
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>');

SELECT  @schema;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple string replace if the xml isn't too big:

```
DECLARE @schemaVARCHAR (MAX)
SET @schemaVARCHAR = CAST(@schema AS VARCHAR(MAX))
SET @schemaVARCHAR = 
    REPLACE(
        @schemaVARCHAR, 
        '<xs:enumeration xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" value="item 1" />',
        ''
    )

SET @schema = CAST(@schemaVARCHAR AS XML)
```

Comment: Then put that in the REPLACE function. Mine was just an example. You can also do this repeatedly if you need to remove/change multiple things.

Comment: The point is that you shouldn't edit XML like it's text. The prefix doesn't matter.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I disagree - the answer has merit. If the completely harmless xml bloat created in this very specific instance is totally unacceptable to the OP then doing a string replace operation is warranted in the interests of sanity. I agree fully with you that treating xml as text is evil.

Comment: @hugh: you've just shown why it is without merit: treating XML as text is evil. To make it more clear: what if a different prefix is used _for each element_?

Answer (score 0):

If your XML isn't too complicated, why not use FOR XML EXPLICIT instead?

Another workaround would be to get generate the XML without the namespace and then add it in afterwards.