# How do I remove redundant namespace in nested query when using FOR XML in SQL Function

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, namespaces, for-xml-path

There is a solution for remove namespace [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242070/how-do-i-remove-redundant-namespace-in-nested-query-when-using-for-xml-path)!, but I need it works in SQL function, I'm getting this error:

> The FOR XML clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and subqueries when they contain a set operator. To work around, wrap the SELECT containing a set operator using derived table syntax and apply FOR XML on top of it.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks Xtyan

From comment: This is the needed XML-output

```
<zoo xmlns:an="uri:animal">
  <an:animal species="Mouse">
    <an:legs>
      <an:leg>Front Right</an:leg>
      <an:leg>Front Left</an:leg>
      <an:leg>Back Right</an:leg>
      <an:leg>Back Left</an:leg>
    </an:legs>
  </an:animal>
  <an:animal species="Chicken">
    <an:legs>
      <an:leg>Right</an:leg>
      <an:leg>Left</an:leg>
    </an:legs>
  </an:animal>
  <an:animal species="Snake" />
</zoo>
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: SQL Server 2008, the same to the link reference

Comment: And why do you think this is connected to namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

You will not like this probably...

I did not find a generic solution for this... It is no problem to create this with repeated namespaces. This is not wrong, but annoying:

```
    declare @xml as xml;

    WITH XMLNAMESPACES('uri:animal' as an)
    select @xml = (
    select 
        a.c2 as "@an:species"
        , (
           select l.c3 as "text()" 
           from t2 l where l.c2 = a.c1 
           for xml path('an:leg'), type
           ) as "an:legs"
    from t1 a
    for xml path('an:animal'),root('zoo'));
```

### One solution: build this via string-concatenation

But this is super-ugly...

### an (almost) working solution...

The following solution uses `FLWOR` to re-create the XML after its creation, but this is not generic. It is necessary to add one element of this namespaces to the `<zoo>`, otherwise the namespace is created on a deeper level repeatedly. I added the attribut `an:Dummy`.

```
create table t1 ( c1 int, c2 varchar(50))
create table t2 ( c1 int, c2 int, c3 varchar(50))
insert t1 values 
(1, 'Mouse'),
(2, 'Chicken'),
(3, 'Snake');
insert t2 values
(1, 1, 'Front Right'),
(2, 1, 'Front Left'),
(3, 1, 'Back Right'),
(4, 1, 'Back Left'),
(5, 2, 'Right'),
(6, 2, 'Left');
GO
--the function

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TestFunc()
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN
    declare @xml as xml;

    WITH XMLNAMESPACES('uri:animal' as an)
    select @xml = (
    select 
        a.c2 as "@an:species"
        , (
           select l.c3 as "text()" 
           from t2 l where l.c2 = a.c1 
           for xml path('an:leg'), type
           ) as "an:legs"
    from t1 a
    for xml path('an:animal'));

    set @xml=@xml.query('declare namespace an="uri:animal";
                         <zoo an:Dummy="dummy">
                         {
                            for $a in /an:animal 
                                return <an:animal an:species="{$a/@an:species}"><an:legs>
                                        {
                                        for $l in $a/an:legs/an:leg
                                        return <an:leg>{$l/text()}</an:leg>
                                        }
                                        </an:legs></an:animal>
                          }
                          </zoo>');


    return @xml;

END
GO
--the call

SELECT dbo.TestFunc();
GO
--clean up

drop function dbo.TestFunc;
drop table t1
drop table t2
```

The result

```
<zoo xmlns:an="uri:animal" an:Dummy="dummy">
  <an:animal an:species="Mouse">
    <an:legs>
      <an:leg>Front Right</an:leg>
      <an:leg>Front Left</an:leg>
      <an:leg>Back Right</an:leg>
      <an:leg>Back Left</an:leg>
    </an:legs>
  </an:animal>
  <an:animal an:species="Chicken">
    <an:legs>
      <an:leg>Right</an:leg>
      <an:leg>Left</an:leg>
    </an:legs>
  </an:animal>
  <an:animal an:species="Snake">
    <an:legs />
  </an:animal>
</zoo>
```

### Previous answer

Okay, I think I got this completely wrong in my first attempt. The following is an example, where a function returns the XML without added namespaces.

I use one of the later answers which builds the inner XML in advance without a namespace and creates the full XML as a second call with a namespace. Please check this out:

```
create table t1 ( c1 int, c2 varchar(50))
create table t2 ( c1 int, c2 int, c3 varchar(50))
insert t1 values 
(1, 'Mouse'),
(2, 'Chicken'),
(3, 'Snake');
insert t2 values
(1, 1, 'Front Right'),
(2, 1, 'Front Left'),
(3, 1, 'Back Right'),
(4, 1, 'Back Left'),
(5, 2, 'Right'),
(6, 2, 'Left');
GO
```

--the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TestFunc()
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN
    declare @xml as xml;
    select @xml = (
    select 
        a.c2 as "@species"
        , (select l.c3 as "text()" 
           from t2 l where l.c2 = a.c1 
           for xml path('leg'), type) as "legs"
    from t1 a
    for xml path('animal'));

    declare @resultXML XML;
    ;with XmlNamespaces( 'uri:animal' as an)
    select @ResultXML= (SELECT @xml for xml path('') , root('zoo'),TYPE);

    return @resultXML;
END
GO
```

--the call

```
SELECT dbo.TestFunc();
GO
```

--clean up

```
drop function dbo.TestFunc;
drop table t1
drop table t2
```

The result

```
<zoo xmlns:an="uri:animal">
  <animal species="Mouse">
    <legs>
      <leg>Front Right</leg>
      <leg>Front Left</leg>
      <leg>Back Right</leg>
      <leg>Back Left</leg>
    </legs>
  </animal>
  <animal species="Chicken">
    <legs>
      <leg>Right</leg>
      <leg>Left</leg>
    </legs>
  </animal>
  <animal species="Snake" />
</zoo>
```

Comment: Shnugo, I only need that the link reference solution works too in one Scalar-valued Function of SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @Xtyan, yes, I think I understand this now: The actual problem is *repeated namespaces*. You try to solve this with `UNION ALL` and get the error mentioned above... Right? Just wrap your `UNION ALL` with `SELECT * FROM (YourSelect) AS Dummy FOR XML PATH() ...` and you can place this within a scalar function. The actual error you describe here has nothing to do with the namespaces but is bound to the usage of `UNION ALL` together with `FOR XML` within one sub-select...

Comment: Hi @Xtyan, is this issue solved? Do you need further help?

Comment: Can you make it work the example that I refer? I tried your suggestions, but I can't solve it.

Comment: @Xtyan, which example are you talking about? Please use the edit option of your question to add more information and code there (What have you tried, what went wrong?). And then please place a comment here with `@Shnugo` to trigger an alert on my side.

Comment: from the begining...There is a solution for remove namespace **"[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242070/how-do-i-remove-redundant-namespace-in-nested-query-when-using-for-xml-path)"**!

Comment: Nice, but I need something like this, with your code:

    <zoo xmlns:an="uri:animal">
     <an:animal species="Mouse">
      <an:legs>
        <an:leg>Front Right</an:leg>
        <an:leg>Front Left</an:leg>
        <an:leg>Back Right</an:leg>
        <an:leg>Back Left</an:leg>
      </an:legs>
     </an:animal>
     <an:animal species="Chicken">
      <an:legs>
        <an:leg>Right</an:leg>
        <an:leg>Left</an:leg>
      </an:legs>
     </an:animal>
     <an:animal species="Snake" />
    </zoo>