# Trouble with Namespaces in T-SQL FOR XML queries

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-namespaces, for-xml

I have a question about using SQL Server FOR XML to create XML documents with namespaces. I need to create a document like below where there is a namespace definition in the root element (`xmlns:ijk="h:/i.j.k"`), and a namespace reference in a child element attribute (`ijk:LMNO="3333"`).

I am generating the XML to POST to a Web service:

```
<ROOT xmlns:ijk="h:/i.j.k" RSTU="1111">
  <CHILD CDEF="2222" ijk:LMNO="3333" />
</ROOT>
```

I wrote this first sample query to get the structure correct before I started fighting with namespaces, and the result is what is expected.

```
SELECT
    [RSTU] = 1111,
    (SELECT
         [CDEF] = 2222, [LMNO] = 3333
     FOR XML RAW('CHILD'), TYPE)
FOR XML RAW('ROOT'), TYPE;
```

Result

```
<ROOT RSTU="1111">
  <CHILD CDEF="2222" LMNO="3333" />
</ROOT>
```

Then I tried using `WITH NAMESPACES` to add the namespaces, but SQL Server gets carried away and adds all namespaces to all elements. The target Web service does not accept the XML with the namespace overload (in my real case, there are four levels of elements and three namespaces, and it makes a real mess).

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('h:/i.j.k' as ijk, 'h:/x.y.z' as xyz)
SELECT
  [RSTU] = 1111,
  (SELECT
       [CDEF] = 2222, [ijk:LMNO] = 3333
  FOR XML RAW('CHILD'), TYPE)
FOR XML RAW('ROOT'), TYPE;
```

Result:

```
<ROOT xmlns:xyz="h:/x.y.z" xmlns:ijk="h:/i.j.k" RSTU="1111">
    <CHILD xmlns:xyz="h:/x.y.z" xmlns:ijk="h:/i.j.k" CDEF="2222" ijk:LMNO="3333" />
</ROOT>
```

I read in Books Online that, while not recommended, namespaces can be added like a regular attribute. I tried this, and it generated the proper namespace definitions:

```
SELECT
    [xmlns:ijk] = 'h:/i.j.k',
    [RSTU] = 1111, 
    (SELECT
         [CDEF] = 2222, [LMNO] = 3333
     FOR XML RAW('CHILD'), TYPE)
FOR XML RAW('ROOT'), TYPE;
```

Result:

```
<ROOT xmlns:ijk="h:/i.j.k" RSTU="1111">
  <CHILD CDEF="2222" LMNO="3333" />
</ROOT>
```

The output above has a good looking namespace definition, but the LMNO attribute does not have its required ijk: namespace reference prefix. I tried adding the namespace reference, but I got an error:

```
SELECT
    [xmlns:ijk] = 'h:/i.j.k',
    [RSTU] = 1111,
    (SELECT
         [CDEF] = 2222, [ijk:LMNO] = 3333
     FOR XML RAW('CHILD'), TYPE)
FOR XML RAW('ROOT'), TYPE;
```

Result:

> Msg 6846, Level 16, State 2, Line 34
>   XML name space prefix 'ijk' declaration is missing for FOR XML column name 'ijk:LMNO'.

Is it possible to write a T-SQL FOR XML query that generates XML where:

1. a namespace is defined only in the root element, and
2. the root element has data attributes other than namespace definitions, and
3. references to the namespace are used in attribute names in child elements?

I reviewed [How do I remove redundant namespace in nested query when using FOR XML PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242070/how-do-i-remove-redundant-namespace-in-nested-query-when-using-for-xml-path). In this topic the root element has only namespace definitions and no data attributes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove redundant namespace in nested query when using FOR XML PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242070/how-do-i-remove-redundant-namespace-in-nested-query-when-using-for-xml-path)

Comment: Please visit [this connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265956), sign in and vote for it. The repeated namespaces with sub-selects are a story for centuries now...

Comment: @Shnugo. I tried the Connect issue, but Connect is being shut down and is now in read-only mode, so, alas, I cannot vote it up.

Comment: @JediSQL These Microsoft people! They do everything to keep this open :-D

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly, but a workaround

```
SELECT
    CAST(REPLACE(CAST(
    (SELECT
    [xmlns:xyz] = 'h:/x.y.z',
    [xmlns:ijk] = 'h:/i.j.k',
    [RSTU] = 1111,
    (SELECT
         [@CDEF] = 2222, [@ns_ijk_LMNO] = 3333
     FOR XML PATH('ROOT'), TYPE)
     FOR XML RAW('CHILD'), TYPE) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'ns_ijk_','ijk:') AS XML);
```

The result

```
<CHILD xmlns:xyz="h:/x.y.z" xmlns:ijk="h:/i.j.k" RSTU="1111">
  <ROOT CDEF="2222" ijk:LMNO="3333" />
</CHILD>
```

By using the `RAW` mode for the outer `SELECT` it is allowed to place namespace declarations just as if they were attributes.

The internal `FOR XML PATH` will not use these namespaces (other behavior with `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`!), but it is not possible to use a namespace prefix there.

So I add something to the attributes name, cast the whole XML to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, replace my dummy and cast it back.

Please go to [the connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265956) and vote. This is really annoying!

The repeated namespaces (when using sub-selects) are not wrong but bloating the output and can clash in validators.

Comment: Yeah, i know i can go to character mode and "touch up" the XML, but I avoid that for these reasons:  

1) When I stick with pure `FOR XML` I always get well formed XML.  
2) The switching back and forth between character data and T-SQL's internal, structured xml storage impacts performance.  
3) It's lame.

Comment: @JediSQL This is very honorable - but then you are lost... Switching back and force *can* have side effects, but should not do any harm. A well formed XML remains well formed. It is slow and ugly, but the only way.

Answer (score 0):

With your result

```
<ROOT xmlns:xyz="h:/x.y.z" xmlns:ijk="h:/i.j.k" RSTU="1111">
    <CHILD xmlns:xyz="h:/x.y.z" xmlns:ijk="h:/i.j.k" CDEF="2222" ijk:LMNO="3333" />
</ROOT>
```

It seems like you have an extraneous `xyz` namespace, but the rest seems valid. Defining a namespace isn't the same as applying a namespace to an element or attribute, and defined namespaces can be ignored if they aren't applied (i.e. prepending as on your `LMNO` element). Defining the namespace twice is redundant but shouldn't be invalid.

XML is a finicky standard so perhaps the probably is really on the validation which 'requires' this.

Doesn't change your problem, of course, but in the same way that validators have strange expectations, many XML generators don't give this type of flexibility over optional values. They often have the 'this is just what you get' approach.

Comment: I included the extraneous `xyz` namespace because the Web service I am POSTing to requires me to include namespace definitions in the root that are not explicitly referenced in the XML document.